# Java logo replace in security prompt

Tags: java

Is it possible to change Java logo in security prompt dialog which occurs when starting an applet?
According to [Java Security Prompts](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/appsecuritydialogs.xml), Java or vendor logo can appear in the dialog. How can default Java logo can be replaced with a vendor logo? 
I can't find any Manifest attributes to set the custom vendor logo.

Comment: I would've thought changing this would be against the Java T&C's, but I can't see anywhere that says this.

Comment: It's just funny to see what people want here in SO.

Comment: Write viruses much? :)  It's a JOKE, ppl. *cough*

Comment: It is a customer's question, not mine. I must provide an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to specify an application icon for an Applet. But Java WebStart supports icons, see the `icon` element within the [JNLP `information` Element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#information).

The icon is used in the loading dialogs and in the list of applications, etc, but I didn’t check whether it is also shown in the security dialog. But it’s the only way to specify an icon at all. So if this doesn’t work, I don’t believe there is any other way.

Comment: *"..I didn’t check whether it is also shown in the security dialog."*  Of course not!  If it were possible to do that, the dire warnings of accepting privileged code might be replaced by a cute animated GIF of a kitten with a 'click to feed meeeooow' message.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: I’m not the one to judge whether a cute kitten or a coffee cup looks more dangerous. I know that this kind of social engineering works even with more hazardous looking dialogs, e.g. if the the app promises “free beer” or “nude women”. So I don’t think that the choice for an icon makes that difference.

Comment: It is hard to judge which icon looks more dangerous. Our client (a bank) wants to put their logo in the dialog. Their clients (end users) are more comfortable when they see the bank logo than the Java cup icon. The mindset of end user is different than mindset of developers :)